# symbolic differentiation in Scala

Tags: scala, math, sicp, symbolic-math

I want to make a symbolic differentiation function in Scala using its pattern matching like done in SICP. I'd want to be able to write something like this:

```
differentiate(exp) = exp match
{
  case + => 
  case * =>
}
```

Is this possible in Scala on 'native' expressions?

Comment: Do you mean `def differentiate (exp: T) = ...`? What type is exp? A String? A function? Both wouldn't be a good fit for just '+' or '*'.

Comment: Perhaps this was the inspiration to your question, but if you didn't see it already, see the extended example in the Pattern Matching chapter of Programming in Scala (http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html)

Comment: @LuigiPlinge It was indeed suggested to me, but I wanted to see if i would need to make this tree myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every examples I've seen before involve an expression tree. You can build it easily in Scala with case classes. For instance, a rough sketch involving pattern matching and object-oriented style:

```
trait Exp {
  def differentiate: Exp
}
case class Const( value: Double ) extends Exp {
  def differentiate = Const(0)
}
case class Var( label: String, power: Double ) extends Exp {
  def differentiate = this match {
    case Var(l,0.0) => Const(0)
    case Var(l,p) => Mul( Const(p), Var(l,p-1) )
  }
}
case class Add( left: Exp, right: Exp ) extends Exp {
  def differentiate = Add( left.differentiate, right.differentiate )
}
case class Mult( left: Exp, right: Exp ) extends Exp {
  def differentiate = ( left, right ) match {
    case ( Const(c), exp ) => Mul( Const(c), exp.differentiate )
    case ( exp, Const(c) ) => Mul( Const(c), exp.differentiate )
    case (e1, e2) => Add( Mul( e1.differentiate, e2), Mul( e1, e2.differentiate ) )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try it? :)

```
sealed trait Exp
case object + extends Exp
case object * extends Exp

def differentiate(exp: Exp) = exp match {
  case + => println("plus")
  case * => println("times")
}

scala> differentiate(*)
times
```

But

```
scala> differentiate(+)
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       differentiate(+)
                  ^
```

Hmm, I guess it doesn't work for all symbols.

Comment: Although you can call it with `differentiate($plus)`.

Comment: Is the issue with ´+´ a bug ?

Comment: @soc I don't know about `+` in particular, but of course you'd expect some symbols (reserved characters like `{`, `;` etc) not to work.

Answer (score 1):

On "native" expressions, no. Not really. You *can* use symbols:

```
def foo(x: Symbol) = x match {
  case '+ => "Plus"
  case '* => "Times"
}
```

If you notice, symbols are also the way that SICP parses things. See [SICP 2.3.1](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html#%_sec_2.3.1)

```
(deriv '(* x y) 'x)
y
```

It might have prettier syntax for matching on symbols, but in the end, that's all that it's doing.